# maven-surefire-plugin is not a valid file

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to run my test, but I have an Exception:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test
>   (default-test) on project UI-test: There are test failures. [ERROR] 
>   [ERROR] Please refer to
>   /Users/mu/Dev/Auto_test/TestUIJenkins/target/surefire-reports for the
>   individual test results. [ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any
>   exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
>   [ERROR] There was an error in the forked process [ERROR] Suite file
>   /src/main/resources/Registrations.xml is not a valid file [ERROR]
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There
>   was an error in the forked process [ERROR] Suite file
>   /src/main/resources/Registrations.xml is not a valid file [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:656)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:282)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:245)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1183)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1011)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:857)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307) [ERROR]
>   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106) [ERROR]
>   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863) [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288) [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199) [ERROR] at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) [ERROR] at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   [ERROR] at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   [ERROR] at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   [ERROR] at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
>   [ERROR] -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of
>   the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven
>   using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For
>   more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read
>   the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

**This is my pom.xml:**

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.13.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>/src/main/resources/Registrations.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

**This is my testng prop file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Registration" verbose="1" >
    <test name="Registration" >
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.Registration"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: First using of `LATEST` as version is deprecated for a very long time...furthermore why do you need a testng.xml file? Have you named your tests based on the naming schema like `*Test.java`? If yes than you don't need to have a `testng.xml` file....Are the tests correctly located in `src/test/java`?

Comment: Thank you, it was my mistake, the problem was in my path folder.

Comment: @khmarbaise I have all test files named as ```*Test.java``` What if I don't want to run each and every test, I want to run only a single java file which is defined in the testng.xml. How do I achieve that, i have exact configuration as the problem.

Comment: I strongly recommend not use an TestNG xml file just let maven-surefire decide which tests are available. If you need a particular test you can do that via `mvn test -Dtest=...`(https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html).. apart from that you should run your tests via IDE and not on command line... also having issues in your file `Suite file /src/main/resources/Registrations.xml is not a valid file`...

Comment: > apart from that you should run your tests via IDE and not on command line.

@khmarbaise, this might be try for personal development, but you need to be able to run your tests from the command line for when you run your CI/CD pipeline

Comment: please read the issue: `Suite file /src/main/resources/Registrations.xml is not a valid file [ERROR]` ... there is the problem...